# Differential inequation problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:[0,1]→\mathbb{R}$ be a function. Suppose the function $f$ is twice differentiable, $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and satisfies $f''(x)-2f'(x)+f(x)\geq e^x$, $x\in [0,1]$.

Which of the following is true for $0<x<1$?

A) $0<f(x)<\infty$

B) $-\frac{1}{2}<f(x)<\frac{1}{2}$

C) $-\frac{1}{4}<f(x)<1$

D) $-\infty<f(x)<0$

---

This appeared in one of my test papers and I went blank over this. I am still out of ideas because I have never come across differential inequations. Moreover, the above inequation is second-order which isn't even in my course. How am I supposed to deal with this?

It would be greatly appreciated is someone could provide a resource or the name of book where these kind of problems are found. Many thanks!

Comment: This appeared in last year's JEE Advanced. Have you tried googling?

Comment: Yes it is and I appeared for it last year. I know there are solutions out there but I don't want to simply look at them because I believe discussing the problem helps one to learn more. Do you have any ideas about where I can find these kind of problems?

Comment: This year's JEE Advanced Paper. :P

Comment: :D

Ah, but please do share a resource if you happen to find one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(f(x)e^{-x})''\ge 1\implies \text{ concave upward }$$

$$f(0)e^{-0}=f(1)e^{-1}=0\implies \text{negative}\implies (D)$$

Comment: I agree with the part concave upward and with the negative part too but I am not seeing how the answer is D. Can you please explain? Thanks!

Comment: @PranavArora All other options have some positive numbers. Also, your function can have large negative values too.

Comment: Yes, I see, thanks Awesome! :)

But I do not see how you instantly thought of writing the inequation as $(e^{-x}f(x))''\geq 1$. Some motivation behind it?

Comment: I had $f''(x)$ and $-f'(x)$ I knew I could split $2$ with other $f(x)$.

Comment: Excellent problem

Answer (score 2):

$$G(x)=e^{-x}f(x)-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2$$
then
$$G'(x)=e^{-x}(f'(x)-f(x))-x$$
$$G''(x)=e^{-x}(f''(x)-2f'(x)+f(x))-1$$
since
$$f''(x)-2f'(x)+f(x)\ge e^x\Longrightarrow G''(x)\ge 0$$
so
$$e^{-1}f'(1)-1>G'(1)>G'(x)>G'(0)=f'(0)-f(0)=f'(0)$$

Comment: Hi math110! How did you think of defining $G(x)$, that looks like a very odd choice (to me). Can you please explain? Thanks!